# Custom WP_Query for search

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to make a custom WP_Query for a search results page.

With the following code, the page always displayed all posts regardless:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```

So I've added the search Query to the `$args`, but this always returns no results - where is this going wrong?

```
<?php

$search_query = get_search_query();

echo $search_query;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    's' => $search_query
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this using pre_get_posts - I'm still intrigued as to why using the WP_Query method doesn't work, but here's what I'm now using:

```
function search_filter($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
      if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '-1');
      }
    }
  }

  add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use the template`search.php` and `searchform.php` as your starting points. Creating a Search Page Codex

2) As far as the custom query goes, you can use pre_get_posts hook to test if you're on a search page, then you get $_GET your values, edit your query accordingly. Action Reference - pre_get_posts

There are tons of tutorials online and questions on this exchange to help you out. Some are Simple and others are more Complex. You'll have to do some real research to accomplish this. Hope it helps!